# Importing CSV to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, csv, adminer

I'm trying to import a csv to a mysql table in my db but I keep getting this error:

> Unknown column '' in 'field list'

```
INSERT INTO `job_budget_report` (`Job_Num`, `Description`, `EngWeekly`, `EngTTD`, `EngBudget`, `DesignWeekly`, `DesignTTD`, `DesignBudget`, `DetailsWeekly`, `DetailsTTD`, `DetailsBudget`, `EjectionWeekly`, `EjectionTTD`, `EjectionBudget`, `CarbonEDMWeekly`, `CarbonEDMTTD`, `CarbonEDMBudget`, `GdrillBMWeekly`, `GdrillBMTTD`, `GdrillBMBudget`, `CNCWeekly`, `CNCTTD`, `CNCBudget`, `MMQCOtherWeekly`, `MMQCOtherTTD`, `MMQCOtherBudget`, `SpottingWeekly`, `SpottingTTD`, `SpottingBudget`, `SpotPLWeekly`, `SpotPLTTD`, `SpotPLBudget`, `HWWeekly`, `HWTTD`, `HWBudget`, `TotalMach`, `TotalOther`, `TotalOFMach`, ``) VALUES
('1000', 'description text here', '0', '0', '0', NULL, '0', '0', NULL, NULL, '0', NULL, '0', NULL, '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '20.5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '18.5', '40', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '');
```

Table Structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeW8x.jpg

Now I realize that theres extra empty fields in that query but how do I remove them from my csv ?

Here's what my csv looks like when I open it in sublime text:

> Job_Num;Description;EngWeekly;EngTTD;EngBudget;DesignWeekly;DesignTTD;DesignBudget;DetailsWeekly;DetailsTTD;DetailsBudget;EjectionWeekly;EjectionTTD;EjectionBudget;CarbonEDMWeekly;CarbonEDMTTD;CarbonEDMBudget;GdrillBMWeekly;GdrillBMTTD;GdrillBMBudget;CNCWeekly;CNCTTD;CNCBudget;MMQCOtherWeekly;MMQCOtherTTD;MMQCOtherBudget;SpottingWeekly;SpottingTTD;SpottingBudget;SpotPLWeekly;SpotPLTTD;SpotPLBudget;HWWeekly;HWTTD;HWBudget;TotalMach;TotalOther;TotalOFMach
>   5710;GM K2XL Bracket FRT 5/D Belt
>   R;0;0;0;;0;0;;;0;;0;;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;20.5;0;0;0;0;0;18.5;40;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;457.56;328.8;;;;;

Sorry I don't know how to structure this nicer, I'll post an image of one of the rows in the excel file before and after I clear formatting as well.

Before:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jdRI.jpg

After:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjjME.jpg

Is there a more efficient way to do this ?

Comment: Pity. If you knew how to "structure this nicer", I suspect you could figure out these sorts of errors for yourself!

Comment: @Strawberry Table structure or excel ? I got handed the excel file from a manager that inputs this data.

Comment: @Strawberry As for when I said I dont know how to structure this nicer I mean't my op with the csv file contents for you guys to see lol

Comment: *I realize that theres extra empty fields* - Not sure you do. The column list in your SQL code ends with an empty column **name**. You just need to not generate invalid code.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fgetcsv()` to read, clean and insert into your table. - http://www.php.net/fgetcsv

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
         $num = count($data);
         echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
         $row++;
         for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
         } 
     }
     fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO `job_budget_report` 
     ( `Job_Num`
     , `Description`
     , `EngWeekly`
     , `EngTTD`
     , `EngBudget`
     , `DesignWeekly`
     , `DesignTTD`
     , `DesignBudget`
     , `DetailsWeekly`
     , `DetailsTTD`
     , `DetailsBudget`
     , `EjectionWeekly`
     , `EjectionTTD`
     , `EjectionBudget`
     , `CarbonEDMWeekly`
     , `CarbonEDMTTD`
     , `CarbonEDMBudget`
     , `GdrillBMWeekly`
     , `GdrillBMTTD`
     , `GdrillBMBudget`
     , `CNCWeekly`
     , `CNCTTD`
     , `CNCBudget`
     , `MMQCOtherWeekly`
     , `MMQCOtherTTD`
     , `MMQCOtherBudget`
     , `SpottingWeekly`
     , `SpottingTTD`
     , `SpottingBudget`
     , `SpotPLWeekly`
     , `SpotPLTTD`
     , `SpotPLBudget`
     , `HWWeekly`
     , `HWTTD`
     , `HWBudget`
     , `TotalMach`
     , `TotalOther`
     , `TotalOFMach`
     , `` -- clearly, this is the offending line!
     ) VALUES 
     ('1000'
     , 'description text here'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , NULL
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , NULL
     , NULL
     , '0'
     , NULL
     , '0'
     , NULL
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '20.5'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '18.5'
     , '40'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , '0'
     , ''); -- and its corresponding value
```